# Create a ticket with an attachment on Sourceforge

Tags: python, python-requests, sourceforge

I am trying to create a ticket with an attachment on a Sourceforge-based issue tracker. Sourceforge uses Apache Allura.

According to [Sourceforge's documentation](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/sourceforge/#/portals/organizations/98f11a03-7ec0-4a34-b001-c1ca0e0c45b1/apis/32951/versions/34322/pages/48288), a ticket has the following structure:

```
POST request to: /p/{project}/{tracker}/new

ticket_form.summary - ticket title
ticket_form.description - ticket description
ticket_form.status - ticket status
ticket_form.assigned_to - username of ticket assignee
ticket_form.labels - comma-separated list of ticket labels
ticket_form.attachment - (optional) attachment
```

I wrote a small Python script using `requests` to create a ticket, but I have not been able to figure out how to include an attachment.

Snippet for creating a ticket without an attachment:

```
import requests

action = "https://sourceforge.net/rest/p/test-sourceforge-api/tickets/new"

url = action + "?access_token=" + token

body = {'access_token':token,
    'ticket_form.description': "Test Description",
    'ticket_form.summary':'Test Title'
    }

r = requests.post(url, data=body)
```

Allura's [source](https://github.com/apache/allura/blob/master/ForgeTracker/forgetracker/tests/functional/test_root.py#L830) contains sample code for creating a ticket with an attachment, but I did not understand how to translate that POST request into something `requests` could use.

How can I create a ticket with an attachment on Sourceforge using `requests`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet for creating a ticket with an attachment:

```
import requests

action = "https://sourceforge.net/rest/p/test-sourceforge-api/tickets/new"

url = action + "?access_token=" + token

body = {'access_token':token,
    'ticket_form.description': "Test Description",
    'ticket_form.summary':'Test Title'
    }

files={'ticket_form.attachment':("myfilename","myfilecontents", 'application/octet-stream')}

r = requests.post(url, data=body, files=files)
```